latest oci-java-sdk 3.42 and spring-boot-starter-web 3.3 not compatible? Linkageerror
I have this minimal gradle.build file and code extracted from spring-boot application that should be able to work with OCI cloud storage. It fails on LinkageError.
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0' //this is causing the error
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'com.oracle.oci.sdk', name: 'oci-java-sdk-addons-resteasy-client-configurator', version: '3.42.0'
    implementation group: 'com.oracle.oci.sdk', name: 'oci-java-sdk-objectstorage', version: '3.42.0'
    implementation group: 'com.oracle.oci.sdk', name: 'oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-jersey', version: '3.42.0'
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

when running the code
package org.example;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.oracle.bmc.ConfigFileReader;
import com.oracle.bmc.auth.ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider;
import com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorage;
import com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient;

public class ObjectStorageConfig {

// Path to OCI config file
String configurationFilePath = "config";
String profile = "DEFAULT";

public ObjectStorage getObjectStorage() throws IOException {

    //load config file
    final ConfigFileReader.ConfigFile
            configFile = ConfigFileReader
            .parse(configurationFilePath, profile);

    final ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider provider =
            new ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider(configFile);

    //build and return client
    return ObjectStorageClient.builder()
            .build(provider);
}

}
i am getting:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/Users/adekc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec/2.0.1.Final/75cdeb26ccf87bc6f9d0f31b5ec4d80aa15b662c/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class to jar:file:/C:/Users/adekc/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec/2.0.1.Final/75cdeb26ccf87bc6f9d0f31b5ec4d80aa15b662c/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.class
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:97)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.client.jersey.JerseyHttpClientBuilder.build(JerseyHttpClientBuilder.java:306)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.BaseClient.setEndpoint(BaseClient.java:422)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.BaseClient.setRegion(BaseClient.java:457)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.setRegion(ObjectStorageClient.java:152)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.BaseClient.<init>(BaseClient.java:169)
    at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.BaseSyncClient.<init>(BaseSyncClient.java:36)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.<init>(ObjectStorageClient.java:49)
    at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient$Builder.build(ObjectStorageClient.java:145)
    at org.example.ObjectStorageConfig.getObjectStorage(ObjectStorageConfig.java:31)
    at org.example.FileService.getFileObject(FileService.java:50)
    at org.example.NewMain.main(NewMain.java:9)

I tried to tinker with versions, but in general, i think I want latest versions of those libraries if possible. But I have no idea how to resolve the problem. Thanks

Using oci-sdk and spring-boot BOMs + using shaded oci-sdk, insead of individual services helped.
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk-bom:3.43.1'
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.3.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk-shaded-full'

    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
}

this also fixes LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath, which I sometimes got after getting rid of the original LinkageError.
